# Which version of AndEngine (gles1 or gles2) should I learn?

Tags: opengl-es, andengine, opengl-es2

I m new to Game Development. I've chosen AndEngine, but there are 2 versions: gles1 and gles2. I tried sample code from both and found that gles2 code is not run on an emulator, but required an actual device. And in gles2 there are also `BaseGameActivity` and `SimpleBaseGameActivity`. I'm a little confused. Which is best?

Comment: Beginners should normally use the newest stable version possible. What do you mean by "requiring an actual device"? All software requires hardware.

Comment: Is [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/should-we-always-prefer-opengl-es-version-2-over-version-1-x) what you're asking?

Comment: For testing code emulator is required but when i tried to run it on emulator it give me this error org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183) and when i search on this error i came to know that it(AngEngine gles2) will work only on actual device(means mobile or tablet) is this true? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know about the AndEngine, but I've gotten gles2 applications to run fast on a virtual device. You just have to create an x86 Ice Cream Sandwich image with HAXM support enabled and host GPU enabled. Unfortunately this only works with pure Java applications or those that have native elements built for x86.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### USE GLES2

AndEngine is a little tricky to get configured properly the first time you try.  I recommend installing the version stored at [RealMayo's github](https://github.com/RealMayo?tab=repositories), which is a stable version.  That's a version of GLES2 and yes, it's definitely worthwhile to use GLES2 over GLES1.  Many new features were added that make life easier, improve performance, and add great features to your games and projects.   When you're ready to install, follow the instructions at [this link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t4858.html) and follow them precisely.

GLES2 **WILL** run on an emulator, I do it every day, so if you're having some problem running your app, you need to show us the log output.  It might be a memory issue if your computer doesn't have enough memory to run the emulator and install it to the emulator.  See [this thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/problem-with-emulator-t8318.html).

### BaseGameActivity versus SimpleBaseGameActivity

> The first thing that we have to realize is that BaseGameActivity for
>   GLES2 (the version we are using) and BaseGameActivity for GLES1 are
>   completely different. When AndEngine updated, so did BaseGameActivity,
>   but a lot of people that were using GLES1 didn’t like the changes and
>   wanted to work with a class they were already familiar with.
>   Therefore, SimpleBaseGameActivity was created for GLES2.
>   SimpleBaseGameActivity is practically the same as BaseGameActivity for
>   GLES1, which is what a lot of the AndEngine developers wanted at the
>   time.

([source](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12754/andengine-gles2-simple-vs-base-gameactivity/)).  My advice (and practice) is to use GLES2 with the BaseGameActivity.